# MySQL - Multiple 2 Columns, Update within Same Table

Tags: mysql, subquery, multiplication

I want to update the `total` column in table: `tbl_orders`, by multiplying the `quantity` column by the `cost` column.

```
UPDATE `tbl_orders` SET 
   total = (SELECT quantity * cost AS n1 FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE orderid = 167 LIMIT 1) 
WHERE orderid= 167 LIMIT 1
```

I've done subquery updates before, but the mysql error returned is:

> You can't specify target table 'tbl_orders' for update in
>   FROM clause

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` it instead.

```
UPDATE  tbl_orders a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  orderid, quantity * cost totalCost
            FROM    tbl_orders 
            WHERE   orderid = 167
        ) b ON a.orderid = b.orderid
SET     a.total = b.totalCost
WHERE   a.orderid = 167
```

if you want to update all `orderid`, remove all `WHERE` clause.